# Set Jetty session cookie name programmatically

Tags: java, cookies, jetty

I'm running in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146112/jsessionid-collision-between-two-servers-on-same-ip-but-different-ports), how can I set session cookie name by code in Jetty 8?

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
sessionHandler.getSessionManager().setSessionCookie("JSESSIONID_"+runningPort);
context.setSessionHandler(sessionHandler);
```

Is wrong, in Jetty8 `SessionManager` `setSessionCookie(String)` was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
SessionManager sm = new HashSessionManager();
((HashSessionManager)sm).setSessionCookie("JSESSIONID_"+activity.WEB_SERVER_PORT);
context.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler(sm));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this problem with Jetty 9.3 and the solution is slightly different:

```
SessionManager sessionManager = new HashSessionManager();
sessionManager.setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 15); //session time out of 15 minutes
HashSessionIdManager idManager = new HashSessionIdManager();
sessionManager.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("JSESSIONID_" + Integer.toString(m_serverSettings.getM_webServerPort()));
sessionManager.setSessionIdManager(idManager);
SessionHandler sessionHandler = new SessionHandler(sessionManager);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Servlet 3.0 Session Configuration , here is a [doc](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-management.html) that could help you.