# Modifying the default JSESSIONID cookie, Scala Lift Framework

Tags: java, scala, servlets, cookies, lift

My goal is to modify the default JSESSIONID cookie (the servlet cookie) but via the scala code.

It works just fine if I directly hard code the values in `web.xml` like below.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionDomain</param-name>
    <param-value>.subdomain.com</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionCookie</param-name>
    <param-value>CustomID</param-value>
  </context-param>

  ...
</web-app>
```

but it does not work when I try to modify it via the scala code below, it is missing some steps I suppose.

**Boot.scala**

```
package bootstrap.liftweb

...
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler


/**
 * A class that's instantiated early and run.  It allows the application
 * to modify lift's environment
 */
class Boot {
  def boot {

    val context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS)
    context.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionCookie", "CustomID")
    context.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionDomain", ".subdomain.com")

    ...
  }
}
```

but the JSESSIONID cookie is still not modified.

I am trying to follow the following Stack Overflow question which kinda looks similar

[Set Jetty session cookie name programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017645/set-jetty-session-cookie-name-programmatically)

According to this solution it is using a `SessionHandler` but I believe in my case I can't use it because I believe by the time `Boot.scala` executes the session is already created and looks like `context.setSessionHandler(...)` throws an error.

**ServletContextHandler.java**

```
...
public class ServletContextHandler extends ContextHandler
{   ...
    public void setSessionHandler(SessionHandler sessionHandler)
    {
        if (isStarted())
            throw new IllegalStateException("STARTED");

        _sessionHandler = sessionHandler;
    }
    ...
}
```

and I am not sure how I can hook it up.

I am using `Lift 2.6` and `Jetty 8`.

Comment: I would say this is more a jetty question than a Lift question. Lift is set up as a servlet filter running inside of Jetty, so the question is best phrased, ‘how can a servlet filter change the JSESSIONID's cookie’. That hinges on getting the current context handler (you're creating a new one), I think. I just set it in web.xml, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it up like below.

build.sbt

```
...

libraryDependencies ++= {
  ...
  Seq(
    ...
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp"        % "8.1.17.v20150415"  % "container,test,compile",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container,test,compile" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
    ...

  )
}

...
```

Boot.scala

```
...

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.HTTPRequestServlet
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.{Request=>JettyReq}

class Boot {
  def boot {

    def servletRequest(req: Req): Box[HttpServletRequest] = for {
      inner <- Box.asA[HTTPRequestServlet](req.request)
    } yield inner.req

    def setCookieDomain(req: Req) = {

      servletRequest(req).foreach { r =>
      {
        val sessionManager = r.asInstanceOf[JettyReq].getSessionManager
        val cookieConfig = sessionManager.getSessionCookieConfig

        cookieConfig.setDomain(".subdomain.com")
      }
      }
    }

    LiftRules.onBeginServicing.append(setCookieDomain)

    ...
  }
}
```